# When to clear input after submitting in chat app

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, material-design, user-experience

In many part of my app, user get to comment on a post, or create a new post him self.

Process I use 
1. User enter his text
2 (click) send
3. Trigger a promise that post message
4. If success add message to stream.
5. If failed so nothing.

My question is what should happens to the input field and submit button while waiting for server response ?

Should I add new message to posts stream while waiting and reset form once user click send or disable them while waiting ?

What is best approach for smooth user experience ? Is there any recommendations regarding that in material design specs ?

Also if I'm using post.id in `track by` If I'm to add post to stream should I sent a random ID ?

```
---example
<post ng-repeat"post in posts track by post.ID" post-data="post">
....post directive template
    <div>
 <input ng-model=ctrl.new_post />
 <button ng-click=ctrl.post(ctrl.new_post)>send< /button>
```

Comment: I'd say disable them while its waiting

Comment: Immediately clear the text input; I would display the pending text in the chat window with a spinner / indicator suggesting that the message is still processing.  Let the messages queue up, and remove the indicator when the promise is resolved.  That way if the promise fails, you can show a failure icon in stream.

Comment: @Michael how would you solve track by problem ?